# Irrlicht server side

Tags: c++, qt, bullet, irrlicht

I'm currently developing a multiplayer game with Irrlicht.

So obviously, on the client side we have Irrlicht, to perform the rendering, and server side we have Bullet to perform the physics calculations.

We are using Qt for the rest (GUI, network, ...).

There is some useful features from Irrlicht, like :

- loading mesh, texture, ... from an archive file without decompressing it.

We have all our resources stored in a TAR file, the server send it to the client, and Irrlicht load it (without decompressing it), really usefull.

But Bullet needs to know the models to perform collision detection, so I need to load the models.

A solution is to develop a TAR parser with Qt and libarchive, and tell Bullet to load it with `ConvexDecomposition::WaveFrontObj`. But a easier solution would be to use Irrlicht to load the mesh from the archive (since the code is already done).

So, is there a way to use Irrlicht, server side, without rendering to a video driver ?

Comment: You will likely need to build your own server and the model you use is highly dependent on your game. Typically, if possible (and secure), minimizing the amount of data sent through the network will provide a better user experience. Irrlicht does not have networking capabilities. You will need to receive information from the server and interpret it properly on the client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a way to use Irrlicht server side.

So, I want Irrlicht to perform some calculations without any rendering. The solution was pretty easy, I just have to create the device with a NULL driver type :

```
SIrrlichtCreationParameters params;
params.DriverType = EDT_NULL;
device = createDeviceEx (params);
```